# How to enable Cognito's "Attribute verification and user account confirmation" from cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito

I've been reading back and forth AWS documentations, but I am not able to find how to proper set the settings shown in the image below using cloudformation template. What I want to achieve is that, when a user signs up, Cognito sends an automatic email with a custom template presenting the user with the code to confirm its account.

[image: AWS Cognito Attribute verification and user account confirmation]

The `template.yml` below creates a resource with:

```
Allow Cognito to automatically send messages to verify and confirm
Disabled
```

And it looks like:

```
# Create Cognito UserPool (i.e., the table with the users)
  UserPool:
    Type: "AWS::Cognito::UserPool"
    Properties:
      UserPoolName: auth-template-user-pool
      UsernameAttributes:
        - email
      VerificationMessageTemplate:
        DefaultEmailOption: CONFIRM_WITH_CODE  
      EmailConfiguration:
        EmailSendingAccount: COGNITO_DEFAULT
      Schema:
        - Name: name
          AttributeDataType: String
          Mutable: true
          Required: true
        - Name: family_name
          AttributeDataType: String
          Mutable: true
          Required: true
        - Name: email
          AttributeDataType: String
          Mutable: false
          Required: true
```

I thought the keys `VerificationMessageTemplate` and `EmailConfiguration` would do the job, but no email is received. However, when using the settings displayed in the image above, I do receive the confirmation code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the key name (AutoVerifiedAttributes) for this feature is quite misleading since it may suggest that the attributes listed are auto-verified once a user has signed up.

Therefore, adding:

```yaml
      AutoVerifiedAttributes:
        - email
```

does the job. Finally, the template must look like:

```yaml
  UserPool:
    Type: "AWS::Cognito::UserPool"
    Properties:
      UserPoolName: auth-template-user-pool
      UsernameAttributes:
        - email
      AutoVerifiedAttributes:
        - email
      VerificationMessageTemplate:
        DefaultEmailOption: CONFIRM_WITH_CODE  
      EmailConfiguration:
        EmailSendingAccount: COGNITO_DEFAULT
```